# Django - Connect to Hive2 server

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

with a Django application am trying to connect to hive2 server as below:

settings.py
[image]

when "python manage.py inspectdb > webapp/models.py" is run to update models.py with classes for data objects of tables I get an error as below:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.hive2' isn't an available database backend.
>   Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
>   'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

After going through the Django docs [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26oi9.png) I understand that only above database servers are supported by Django however would like to know if there is any way of accessing HIVE2 server in Django, I have a python standalone script which is able to connect to hive2 server and print results in shell as below, is there any way of coupling Django and this script so I can show my table to user in a front-end:

dbconnect.py

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
import pandas as pd 
conn = connect(host='zzzzzzzz', port=0001, auth_mechanism='PLAIN', user="xxxxxx", password="yyyyy")

query = "select * from table1 limit 5" 
cur = conn.cursor()
try:
  cur.execute(query)
  rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print (row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Connect to the database once when you run the project through `settings.py`.
2. Make a global `conn` object to use in any module.
3. Import that `conn` object whenever you want to make DB operations (e.g. in `views.py`).

**Example:**

In `settings.py`:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
import pandas as pd 

DATABASE_CONN = connect(host='zzzzzzzz', 
                        port=0001, 
                        auth_mechanism='PLAIN', 
                        user="xxxxxx", 
                        password="yyyyy")
```

Then in `views.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings

conn = settings.DATABASE_CONN


def test_view(request)
    query = "select * from table1 limit 5" 
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
      cur.execute(query)
      rows = cur.fetchall()
    ...
```